# What does "The beggared turn up" mean here

Tags: meaning-in-context

The failure by the National Union of Namibian Workers (NUNW) to fill the Windhoek Youth complex to capacity during the May Day celebrations has raised eye-brows with curious questions arising concerning its influence and its ability to mobilise the workers.

The beggared turn up at the youth complex also saw the head of state, President Hage Geingob snubbing the event altogether and his speech had to be delivered by the Swapo secretary general, Sophia Shaaningwa.

Comment: My dictionary does not show "beggared" as an adjective at all.  And the verb "beggar" means "to reduce someone to poverty."  Perhaps Namibian English has other meanings for this word?  Or perhaps it is an error; maybe for "The meager turn up".

Comment: Also, the sentence is grammatically incorrect unless you hyphenate "turn-up". Otherwise, it begins by talking about a crowd of "beggared" people turning up at the youth complex, but stops making sense after that.

Comment: @GEdgar: you can make ***any*** verb past participle into an adjective. Sometimes it doesn't make any sense to do so, as appears to be the case here. But, for example, *"the parenthesized expression"* is perfectly good English, and the first two dictionaries I checked didn't show *"parenthesized"* as an adjective.

Comment: I would interpret it to mean "the meager turn-out".  I've seen "beggared" used to mean "meager" a few times.  "Turn up", in this sense, is new to me, but could easily be idiomatic somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

"Turn-up" here is a noun, and should have a hyphen. Confusion with the verb "to turn up" (to arrive) creates a mis-reading of the adjective "beggared" as a noun - it's not. Here's the sentence with corrected punctuation.

- The beggared turn-up at the youth complex also saw the head of state, President Hage Geingob snubbing the event altogether, and his speech had to be delivered by the Swapo secretary general, Sophia Shaaningwa.

It's still not very clearly written, but once "turn-up" is identified as a noun (meaning attendance), "beggared" is clearly an adjective, formed from **to beggar**, a verb meaning "to make poor".

You can replace "beggared" with **paltry**, **scant**, **poor**, **small** (in the sense of a crowd) and not change the meaning of the sentence, which is this:

- A very small number of people arrived at the youth complex, and the head of state, President Hage Geingob snubbed the event altogether - his speech had to be delivered by the Swapo secretary general, Sophia Shaaningwa.